# Synchronize single c header file between two projects

Tags: c, git, header-files

I have a radio chip (connected to an embedded processor) which I have written a library for. I want to develop the protocol to use with the rf chip on a PC (Ubuntu). In order to do so I have copied the header file of my library  into a new folder, but created an entirely new implementation in a new c file and compile for the PC with gcc. This approach has worked better than expected and I'm able to prototype code that calls the rf lib on the PC and simply copy it right over to the real project with little or no changes.

I do have one small problem. Any changes I make in the the library's header file need to be manually copied between the two project folders. Not a big deal, but since this has worked so well, I can see doing things like this again in the future, and would like to link the API headers between the real and "emulated" environments when doing so. I have thought about using git submodules to do so, but I'm not fond of lots of folders in my projects especially if most of them only contain one or two files each. I could use the c preprocessor to swap in the right code at compile time, but that doesn't cover the changes in my Makefile to call the right compiler with the right fags.

I'm wondering if anyone else has ever done something similar, and what their approach was?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you merge the file of your two projects into single directory? Then you will have two makefiles listing different sources, but the header will be one.

Comment: yes and no. See my comment to dshepherd's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should create a "rflib" and treat it as an external library that you use within your embedded project.
develop on one side and update to the newest version on the other.

Comment: I had considered this using a git submodule, but it seemed a bit overkill for a single header file. It doesn't make sense to include the c implementation files in the lib since they are specific the the hardware and software environment and not really generic.

Comment: @Enoch247 i think it makes much sense to also include the implementation. the rflib project should have an include direcory that contains the interface definitions and a source directory that is split up into subdirs with the sources for the different platforms. e.g. src/x86, src/avr, src/A9 or whatever. for small libraries I would omit the binary distribution and directly add the sources to the makefile of the project that uses the lib. this removes the trouble about thinking about static libs or dynamic libs and compatible versions of common used libs.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious (but fairly hacky) solution is to use a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

I think the best solution, since they will share so much code, would be to just merge the two projects and have two different makefile targets for the binaries.

Comment: Merging them may be my best option. The PC implementation is the result of trying to emulate the embedded version, so they are of the same project. Too this end I even thought of making the PC implementation a branch or fork of the embedded version, but I think that keeping branches/forks synchronized as time goes by can be difficult and not really what they were designed for. The only drawback is that I will eventually create another embedded implementation for a different hardware platform that probably should not be merged into this project...